# Grease pencil layer transparent in compositing

Tags: transparency, grease-pencil, compositing-nodes

my grease pencil layer is transparent in my compositing scene (As you can see in the picture below we can see building backgroung scene through the character). I do not understand since my material parameters seem to be ok (strengh 1). Any idea about the issue?
Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]